# Google Tasks API recent version still has daily limit restriction on usage or calls?

Tags: .net, google-tasks-api

It looks like, in earlier Task API releases, we had a restriction on the API call usage with a daily limit. Is that now removed and made unlimited as how our Contacts and Calendars API are?

Please someone confirm on this or, still we have the daily limit restriction for Google Tasks API usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check any limits/quotas for your API key / account at https://code.google.com/apis/console#:services

Comment: Thanks yahia.. I got that n it hasnt changed yet :-)